# Is there a word for naming something/someone with a common descriptor?

Tags: single-word-requests, puns

Is there a word for naming something/someone with its common descriptor—for example, calling a baby, Baby, a cat, Cat, a teddy-bear, Teddy?
It's not an eponym or an aptronym, though there are elements in common, but it feels as if there should be some term for it, even if not entirely serious.

e.g.,
Holly Golightly lives with the cat she calls Cat/with the XX named Cat.

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: I've never heard such a word, but maybe the folks in [linguistics.se] have a technical term for it.

Comment: Perhaps a quick jaunt through TVTropes would suit you: it’s not one word, but there is a page [for your example specifically](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ADogNamedDog)! See also [Exactly What It Says on the Tin](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ExactlyWhatItSaysOnTheTin). More technically, the closest things I can find are [hypernymy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hypernym) and [*totum pro parte*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totum_pro_parte), the whole-from-part kind of metonymy.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've added an example as indicated by @KillingTime.

Comment: As @elutionary mentions, TVTropes has a category that is so close, but doesn't give a term, so quite probably there isn't one!

Comment: Perhaps there is no name for this phenomenon, because it is uncommon: notice that Holly Golightly's giving this name to her cat is a part of the quirkiness of her character.

Comment: Sorry, but a word cannot be a descriptor of itself. It is just using a word as a name.

Comment: "Newspaper" might be a better example than Cat. Proper names, categories, and ordinary nouns have differing usage quirks, like how determiners appear with them. And *Cat* is short for *Catherine*

Comment: Not an answer, but some more - exalted - examples might be "The Prophet" for Mohammed, "The Buddha" for Gautama, and "The Philosopher" for Aristotle.  The phenomenon is not confined to popular culture.

Comment: There appears to be no specific term. Related concepts: _self-reference_, 
_autological word_ , _aptronym_ but they don't exactly fit. _Self-referential naming_ could be used.

Comment: Many thanks for you comments and suggestions. I think I'm going to go with "self-referential" as suggested by @ermanen, but maybe just "simply" or "unimaginatively" would be cleaner!