# What is it called when a moon is called the 'Moon', or a cat named 'Cat' or a film titled 'Film'?

Tags: proper-nouns

I'd love to research more of these instances of naming something after what it is.
What is this called?
Where can I find other examples?

Comment: [Breakfast at Tiffany](https://www.reddit.com/r/notmycat/comments/14bxabo/holly_golightlys_not_her_cat_named_cat_is_a_major/), the protagonist Holly Golightly had a cat called "Cat". I'm not sure there is another satellite called "Moon", or a river that is named only "River". But you never know.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this has been asked before. It's essentially the opposite of genericisation, but specificisation (M-W gives the verb) is broader than the linguistic sense.

Comment: See also [this](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ADogNamedDog)

Comment: Also a duplicate of [Is there a word for naming something/someone with a common descriptor?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/613513/).

Comment: *Moon* is a rather different case from *Cat* or *Film*. It was established as a proper name well before humans had the framework of astronomical knowledge that created the possibility of using it as a common noun.